# Piecewise function is it continuous?

Tags: piecewise-continuity

Let

```
       ⎧ -x+b,           if x < -3  
f(x) = ⎨ 2,              if x = -3  
       ⎩ (−2)/(x−b) + 1, if x > -3 (and x≠b)
```

What I tired is to set -x + b = $(−2)\over(x−b)$ + 1 where x is approaching -3.
I get  b = $7±\sqrt{33}\over{-2}$. Which is incorrect? please help!

a) For what value(s) of *b* is f continuous at -3?

b) For what value(s) of *b* does f have a removable discontinuity at -3?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why were you trying to set $-x + b = \frac {-2}{x-b} + 1$?? That is completely pointless.

To have $f(x)$ continuous at $-3$, you need to have $$\lim_{x\to -3}f(x) = f(-3)$$
Because $f(x)$ is defined differently on each side of $-3$, it is useful to break the full limit into one-sided limits. So the condition becomes:

$$\lim_{x\to -3-}f(x) = f(-3)\\\lim_{x\to -3+}f(x) = f(-3)$$

Now $f(-3) = 2$, while $\lim_{x\to -3-}f(x)$ only involves the behavior of $f(x)$ for values of $x < -3$ and $\lim_{x\to -3+}f(x)$ only involves the behavior of $f(x)$ for values of $x > -3$.

$f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $-3$ if $\lim_{x\to -3}f(x)$ converges, but $\lim_{x\to -3}f(x) \ne f(-3)$. $\lim_{x\to -3}f(x)$ converges if both one-sided limits converge, and are equal. So a removable discontinuity requires

$$\lim_{x\to -3-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to -3+}f(x)$$

Also note that $\lim_{x\to -3-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -3+}f(x)$ are *numbers*. When you compute each of them, the value will not involve "$x$" at all (they will involve $b$, since the function $f$ is defined in terms of $b$, but $x$ is only a dummy variable - the value of the limit does not depend on it).